# WebApp project on NetBeans shows: "Node.js: Missing node.js sources (in NodeJsWebApplication)"

Tags: node.js, netbeans, npm

I installed NetBeans IDE 8.2.
I created a new project:  [image]

I keep receiving error:

> Node.js: Missing node.js sources (in NodeJsWebApplication)

[image]

I pressed on `Resolve..` but it opens the `Options` window and all the settings looks OK:
[image]

In the [NetBeans forums](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247847) they wrote that restarting the IDE should solve it but I tried it and it doesn't help.

I have Node.js version v6.11.2 and Express vesrion 4.16.0.

I tried to install `npm` but in the terminal it writes:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "install"
npm WARN NodeJsWebApplication@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN NodeJsWebApplication@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN NodeJsWebApplication@1.0.0 No license field.
Done.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed to download the sources.
Notice on my question picture "Not downloaded".

I pressed the `Download..` button and it started to download the sources:
[image]

The error disappeared.